# XGBoost custom loss function multi class

Tags: r, xgboost, loss-function

I am trying to implement my own custom loss function for a multi class problem in XGBoost. To start off I wanted to replicate the `multi:softprob` behavior. My code in R:

```
softmaxobj=function(preds,dtrain){
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  labels=model.matrix(~factor(labels))
  preds=apply(preds,1,function(x){exp(x)/sum(exp(x))})
  grad=preds-labels
  hess=2*preds*(1-preds)
  return(list(grad = as.numeric(grad), hess = as.numeric(hess)))
}
```

However after debugging I found that the preds argument returns a vector and not a matrix (as I expected) with length of labels and all 0 values. Why is that? Where can I find the original `multi:softprob` code?

Comment: Seems to be a (yet) unresolved issue https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2776, https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4288.